# Is the keyword "virtual" optional or mandatory in a overridable method?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, virtual-functions

In C #, why we don't have a compilation error even if we forget the keyword "Virtual" in a method of a base class, redefined in a derived class.
I learnded that this keyword is  mandatory to override a method
is not it ?

```
public class Mother
{
    public  void  Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mother !");
    }
}
public class Son : Mother
{
    public  void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Son!!");
    }
}
```

Should  be :

```
public class Mother
{
    public virtual  void  Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mother !");
    }
}
public class Son : Mother
{
    public  override void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Son!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code.  You're doing something wrong or you question just isn't clear enough.  **Always include your code**.

Comment: You should provide an example

Comment: To override a method, the `override` keyword is mandatory not `virtual`.

Comment: The difference is that you hide the method if you omit the virtual keyword, and not override it.

Comment: You should have a compiler warning that you are hiding the base implementation.

Comment: @Crowcoder -- compiler *error*

Comment: @rory.ap its a warning (CS0108), maybe check your facts before correcting someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Virtual and Override works on dynamic binding. The dynamic binding will be decided at run-time Compiler doesn't know that which virtual method will override in the derived class. That why it doesn't give you an error. This will be decided at run-time. Which derived class will be using at run-time.